# Simulate wildcard type parameters (with distinct identities) in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generic-type-parameters

Say I have a simple type like:

```ts
interface X <A, B> {
  getA(): A;
  acceptB(b: B);
}
```

and a function that takes any kind of `X`:

```ts
function fun <V extends X <any, any>> (v: V) {
  v.acceptB(v.getA());
}
```

Above currently compiles because the generic type `X` has been instantiated with the type parameters `any, any`, but this is not type-safe as the actual types of `A` may not be a sub-type of `B`.

In languages like Java, there are wildcard types with distinct identities so that one can do `X<?, ?>`, and above will not compile because `?-1` is not a subtype of `?-2`.

In TypeScript, one can do: `function fun<A, B, V extends X<A, B>> (v: V) {`, but you can see this can get quickly out of hand if one is working with a central generic type with a lot of type parameters.

Thus, is there a better way of simulating the wildcard behaviour?

Comment: I think `function fun<A, B, V extends X<A, B>> (v: V)` is the best we can do

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Now imaging the actual type has 5 type parameters, three of which has a bound. Typing these out alone is almost a line long...

Comment: BTW, is there a reason why `V` needs to be a type parameter?  That is, a reason why you're not doing `fun<A,B>(v: X<A,B>)`?

Comment: @jcalz The function is for illustration purposes. The actual generic type is being used as generic type parameters of various other classes.